# Is it possible to delete a Test Marketplace with Balanced Payments API?

Tags: balanced-payments

I'm using balanced payments [ruby api](https://www.balancedpayments.com/docs/ruby) and accidentally created a couple of extra test marketplaces. While the api exposes a clear interface for creating a test marketplace, I can't seem to find any way to delete one, even without the api. Anyone know of a method to delete a marketplace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current best practice for test marketplaces on Balanced is to simply forget about the marketplace. Balanced will automatically purge unused *test* marketplaces **90** days after the last recorded activity.

Production marketplaces are never deleted.

If you wish to ensure that a test marketplace is *not* deleted then you must perform an authenticated operation on the marketplace at least every 89 days. This could be something simple like making a GET request on the marketplace.